# How to generate an identical random variable in sas

Tags: sas

I want to create a variable `want` which is a randomly generated number following uniform distribution for dataset `data`. I want the number to be the same for all rows. I tried the following:

```
data data; set data; want = ranuni(0) ; run;
```

But this gives different value for each row.

I also tried to generate a macro variable then pass the value to the dataset, but I am struggling to make it work. Can anyone teach me how to do it please?

I tried the following:

```
%let want1= %ranuni(0) ;
```

I also tried:

```
%let want1= %eval ( ranuni(0) );

data data;
set data;
want = &want1;
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the same value on every observation use the RETAIN statement to prevent SAS from resetting the value when it starts the next iteration of the data step.

```
data want;
  set have;
  if _n_=1 then myvar = ranuni(0) ; 
  retain myvar;
run;
```

To use functions in macro code you need to use the %SYSFUNC() macro function.

```
%let mvar = %sysfunc(ranuni(0));

data want;
  set have;
  retain myvar &mvar ;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `%sysfunc` to code gen a fixed random number assigned within the `DATA` step.

```
data data; 
  set data;
  want = %sysfunc(ranuni(0));
run;
```

Here is an `SQL` version using the same for comparison:

```
proc sql;
  alter table have add want num;
  update have set want=%sysfunc(ranuni(0));
quit;
```